# Disabling a cck field with form alter in DRUPAL

Tags: drupal, drupal-views

I know that we can't modify a cck fied in hook alter like a standard field of a standard drupal form.

Comment: how about trying to hide it using theme layer?

Comment: See here: http://drupal.org/node/726282

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can alter it, just like any other form. You must just make sure your hook is ran after the CCK, only then do you have the full CCK-ed form available.

You do that by setting weights in the system table.

Comment: ok thx, i will test it, i get the answer here: http://dominiquedecooman.com/blog/drupal-how-disable-form-element-cck-form-using-form-alter